# Is there any way with maplibre gl to know if a path between two points passes over a coordinate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, maplibre-gl

everyone,
I have the coordinates of the toll booths in Mexico and when they trace a route I want to know if it goes through that coordinate. There are apis that solve this, however the SCT makes this data public and I would only need what I mentioned

I was looking through the documentation but I did not find any function or examples that perform that function

Comment: TurfJS is a useful toolbox for this kind of thing. https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanPointOnLine

Comment: Probare esta opcion aver que sale..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.